# Considerations for using `/tmp` directory on multi-user systems

Tags: bash, directory, tmp, multi-user, single-user

As I've been learning more about Ubuntu and bash programming I've been storing variables in `/tmp`. For example in-between calls to the same bash script I want to record the previous state.

On my current single user system there is no danger of conflicts in `/tmp` directory. However I want my code to be future-proof and wonder if I should get in the habit of using a directory called `~/tmp`?

Perhaps it should be `~/.tmp` and hidden. Perhaps it should be `~/temp` so as not to be confused with conventional `/tmp` directory.

Any ideas / suggestions are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I prefer to use `/tmp` but name the files with some randomness attached to the filename.  `head /dev/urandom | tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 | head -c 13 ; echo ''` I'm sure this has it's own set of caveats.

Comment: I'm using fixed names hard coded in the script. ie `/tmp/lock-screen-timer-remaining` which contains a single line with "30 minutes",  "29 minutes" ...

Comment: At a minimum, you could use `$$`variable in `bash` script as part of the file, as your process ID should be unique in a running system. Or create a user directory in `/tmp`. The advantage of `/tmp`directory is that it is emptied at reboot when properly configured.

Comment: @ridgy The process ID will change each time the script is called. Other scripts reading the status needs a static file name to open. I like your idea of creating a user directory within `/tmp` do you know if it's common practice?

Comment: Assuming we talk about some current Ubuntu, just have a look at /tmp (`ls -l /tmp`), to see what applications do (all directories owned by you are created for you, and some will have your username in the directory name...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally if you wish to store the state for each user the easiest way is to just create a dedicated directory for the application in the users home directory:

```
CFGDIR="${HOME}/.mycoolapp"
mkdir -p ${CFGDIR}
# read / write files in ${CFGDIR} here..
```

If you just want a temporary storage for one instance of the script, a good approach is to use mktemp. For example:

```
TMPDIR="$(mktemp -d)"
# read / write files in ${TMPDIR} here..
rm -rf ${TMPDIR}
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Congrats on your first answer. Notable the first answer on a question two and a half months old :)

Comment: Thanks @WinEunuuchs2Unix - yeah I too was surprised to see no answers on this one.